# Change Wordpress Admin Template Drop-down to a radio

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, admin, custom-backend

What I am trying to do is change the admin template drop down to a radio button with the name of the template and a icon of what the template will look like. The problem is that is that when I select a template is does not save as that template.

Here is what I have so far.

```
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="page_template"><?php _e('Page Template') ?></label>
<!--<select name="page_template" id="page_template">
<option value='default'><?php _e('Default Template'); ?></option>
<?php page_template_dropdown($template); ?>
</select>-->


<form name="page_template" id="page_template">
    <span style="display:block; height:35px; clear:both;">
        <input type="radio" value='default'>
            <img style="top:6px;position:relative;padding-right:5px;" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/page-icons/gallery-icon.jpg" /><?php _e('Default Template'); ?>
    </span>
    <span style="display:block; height:35px; clear:both;">
        <input type="radio" value='gallery'>
            <img style="top:6px;position:relative;padding-right:5px;" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/page-icons/gallery-icon.jpg" /><?php _e('Main Gallery'); ?>
    </span>
</form>
```

I am editing the meta-box.php in the wp-admin > includes folder. Any Help would be great.

Comment: I think your inputs need the `page_template` name attribute, not the form

Comment: I think that is the right call because it is selecting the default template but when I change over to the gallery template is still pulls the default template? Not sure why if you have any suggestion I would be open to them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was going to reply to your latest comment, because I can't test this right now.  I think either I misunderstand you or you misunderstand me.

I would expect the behaviour you're seeing (the default template to be selected) if nothing is passed, which  I think is what would be happening with your current code.

Try replacing everything - including your `<form>` tags - with:

```
    <span style="display:block; height:35px; clear:both;">
        <input type="radio" name="page_template" value='default'>
            <img style="top:6px;position:relative;padding-right:5px;" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/page-icons/gallery-icon.jpg" /><?php _e('Default Template'); ?>
    </span>
    <span style="display:block; height:35px; clear:both;">
        <input type="radio" name="page_template" value='gallery'>
            <img style="top:6px;position:relative;padding-right:5px;" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/page-icons/gallery-icon.jpg" /><?php _e('Main Gallery'); ?>
    </span>
```

That's what I meant in my first comment - move the `name="page_template"` attribute onto your `input` tags.  I don't think you need to introduce a new `<form>` where there wasn't one before.